# Looping over associative array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding a bunch of input fields into an associative array. I can access the individual elements fine, eg. this works:

```
arr = new Array();
field = document.getElementById("someField");
arr[field] = someValue;
alert(arr[field].id);
```

But when I try to loop over them, the `id` shows up as `undefined`, and only one element is looped over.

```
for (var elem in arr) {
    alert(elem.id + " " + arr[elem]);
}
```

Am I looping over it wrong?

**Edit:** `arr.length` shows up as 0 for some reason even though I'm able to access its elements.

Comment: You shouldn't use for-in loops to loop over an array. Use a regular for loop instead.

Comment: @watson Interesting - why?

Comment: @Yuck Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/603003

Comment: @Yuck This answer also has some good info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: @ComFreek Great reference, thank you.

Comment: Your arr is an object, not an array. Arrays are only for numerically indexed stuff in JavaScript

Comment: You seem to be expecting JavaScript to behave like some other language you already know. Why is that?

Comment: @user2736012 Just a lack of knowledge and experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the key in a javascript-array has to be a number or string.
`field` is *automatically* converted  to a string with `toString()`.

```
arr = new Array();
field = document.getElementById("someField");
var key = field.toString();
arr[key] = someValue;
alert(arr[key].id);
```

in your for-loop, you iterate the keys of that array.
`field.toString()` in that case.
and a string does not have a `id`-property.

this will work:

```
for (var elem in arr) {
    alert(arr[elem].id + " " + arr[elem]);
}
```

by the way `toString()` of a DOM-Element ist often a generic string like "[SpanElement]".
if you try to add multiple span-elements, you're effectivle overriding the item with "[SpanElement]" as key and end up with just one element.

in respect to @user2736012 comments, i encourage everyone to read 
"[JavaScript Associative Arrays Demystified](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/)"

Comment: The `key` can be any value, but it's automatically converted to a string. Your `field.toString()` isn't necessary, and won't give the desired result if you're expecting it to serialize the element or something.

Comment: it's for demonstrational purposes ;)

Comment: I didn't know about the string/number restriction. Changed it to work with strings only and it's good now, thanks!

Comment: @idlackage: There is no string/number restriction. It'll accept any value that can be converted to a string, which in JavaScript is any value. It's just that you'll get the string conversion as the key. Also, this answer is still using the wrong type. The `Array` should not be used here.

Answer (score 1):

Any associative array in JavaScript is an object. Arrays are objects that have special methods because they are numerically indexed. So your code should look something like this:

```
obj = {};
field = document.getElementById("someField");
obj[field] = someValue;

for (var p in obj) {
    alert(obj[p].id);
}
```